# aws-lambda no logstream for S3 triggered invoke

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am going through the tutorial currently at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

I finally got the lambda function to work, but I cannot see any logs when it is invoked from the S3 Trigger.

I upload a file to my source bucket. Then look in the destination bucket, and sure enough a new thumbnail has been added. I made sure to delete all files and logs, so no remnents get in the way of my testing. It works fine.
When I go to CloudWatch, I see no log stream beyond the initial streams I did by performing a test from the AWS console with a test event.

If I go and click "Test" again with the test event, I see a log stream for that.

So, the logs work for test events but not when the lamda is invoked from the S3 Trigger. What can I check?

Answer (score 0):

> So, the logs work for test events but not when the lambda is invoked
>   from the S3 Trigger. What can I check?

well this is not possible, unless you change permission between Test &  actually putting file in bucket. However by default lambda has permission to cloud-watch.

This might be because Lambda is not getting triggered 
Go to Source bucket & check in event section, you should be able to see if your event is created.
Create a temporary lambda which prints only "hello", configure your event to trigger this lambda.  You should get Log stream, if thats case "Event was not configured properly".
You should add screenshot of "Event" and lambdas "Designer" section.

Edit:
just make sure you are in Right region, when you are viewing Cloudwatch logs, Lambdas, S3 bucket should also be in same region.